# Directories with space at the end are only traversable in Cygwin

Tags: python, windows, filesystems, whitespace

At the office they were experiencing some mystical errors dealing with undeletable folders and files that disappeared. After some deep digging, I found out the cause: a directory with a space at the end had been created in OS X, and after syncing this using Bittorrent Sync, the directory had been recreated with the space at the end. Unfortunately, file and folder names having a space at the end cause all kinds of problems in Windows, and the fix was simply to remove the space at the end. Renaming in Windows actually proved quite difficult using CMD or Explorer, so I thought I would circumvent the problem by writing a Python script.

Unfortunatly, `os.walk` in Python had the same problem: it would not traverse into the directories containing a space at the end. Then I tried running the same script under Cygwin, and that worked just fine! It traversed into all the directories without problems.

So my question is simply:
*can I write a python script that will successfully traverse directories containing a space at the end when running under a normal Python (non-cygwin) installation in Windows?*

--
For reference, here is the output from the two different runs:

**Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.9.1 (64-bit)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:49:15) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32**

```
C:\Users\Carl-Erik>python space_remover.py   folder-experiment
('folder-experiment', ['my folder'], ['a_file.txt', 'My folder with space '])
('folder-experiment\\my folder', [], [])
```

**Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2012, 13:50:09)**
**[GCC 4.5.3] on cygwin**

```
$ python space_remover.py folder
('folder-experiment', ['my folder', 'My folder with space '], ['a_file.txt'])
('folder-experiment/my folder', [], [])
('folder-experiment/My folder with space ', ['dir1', 'folder_with_space2 '], ['another_file.txt'])
('folder-experiment/My folder with space /dir1', [], [])
('folder-experiment/My folder with space /folder_with_space2 ', ['space_folder3 '], [])
('folder-experiment/My folder with space /folder_with_space2 /space_folder3 ', [], [])
```

Comment: I've no data or authority, but whimsically speculate that the answer might be 'no' because python is simply telling the operating system to traverse the file system then presenting it's responses; so python can only see what the OS sees.

Comment: On the other hand, CygWin somehow magically is able to extract the info it needs, so somewhere deep in the os internals one might find the key, perhaps? On the other hand, then it might no longer be cross-platform runnable.

Comment: Not too magical: the *nix drivers know how to handle the challenge but the dos drivers don't.  What format is the disk in? It's a long-shot but, if you're really keen, perhaps you can read the disk in a raw format and parse it manually. Good luck with that :-)

Comment: haha, as if I would do that :-) It's far easier to just install Cygwin. the disk is a ntfs drive.

Comment: You might get lucky and find a forensic library that can find and change it. [Something like this maybe](http://www.williballenthin.com/forensics/indx/).  Fun day for someone.